# Temporal filtering (monthly) does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count how many tasks each letter has, filtered by month (previous and current). It correctly groups the letters but does not filter the month, and all the duplicate counts appear in both columns. Once I have this figured out, I'd like to do a rate between month and month in one more column. I feel that the solution is close, but I have not been able to find it yet. How far am I?

This is my script:

```
SELECT
    column1 AS 'letter',
    COUNT(`tasks`.`created_at` >= str_to_date(concat(date_format(date_add(now(6), INTERVAL -1 month), '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
        AND `tasks`.`created_at` < str_to_date(concat(date_format(`tasks`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')) AS `previous`,
    COUNT(`tasks`.`created_at` >= str_to_date(concat(date_format(`Lead Task Logs`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
        AND `tasks`.`created_at` < str_to_date(concat(date_format(date_add(now(6), INTERVAL 1 month), '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')) AS `current`
FROM my_table
GROUP BY
    str_to_date(concat(date_format(`tasks`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY
    str_to_date(concat(date_format(`tasks`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
;
```

This is the output that I get:

| letter | previous | current |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 4 |
| A | 3 | 3 |
| B | 8 | 8 |
| C | 4 | 4 |
| D | 12 | 12 |
| D | 3 | 3 |
| E | 2 | 2 |
| E | 2 | 2 |

This is the output that I want:

| letter | previous | current |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 3 |
| B | 8 |  |
| C | 4 |  |
| D | 12 | 3 |
| E | 2 | 2 |

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Comment: Ideally, please put it in a dbfiddle and post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite catch what do you want to achieve, but based on your example, I think you can do it like this

```
SELECT
  A.letter
  , A.Previous
  , CASE
     WHEN B.Current = A.Previous THEN '-'
     ELSE B.Current
    END AS Current
FROM
(SELECT
    column1 AS 'letter',
    COUNT(`tasks`.`created_at` >= str_to_date(concat(date_format(date_add(now(6), INTERVAL -1 month), '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
        AND `tasks`.`created_at` < str_to_date(concat(date_format(`tasks`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')) AS `previous`,
FROM my_table
GROUP BY
    str_to_date(concat(date_format(`tasks`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'
ORDER BY
    str_to_date(concat(date_format(`tasks`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
    column1 AS 'letter',
    COUNT(`tasks`.`created_at` >= str_to_date(concat(date_format(`Lead Task Logs`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
        AND `tasks`.`created_at` < str_to_date(concat(date_format(date_add(now(6), INTERVAL 1 month), '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')) AS `current`
FROM my_table
GROUP BY
    str_to_date(concat(date_format(`tasks`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'
ORDER BY
    str_to_date(concat(date_format(`tasks`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') B ON B.letter = A.letter
;
```